# Alacritty Desktop Entry doesn't show on GNOME 41.1 / Fedora 35

Tags: fedora, gnome

I followed [this guide](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/master/INSTALL.md#desktop-entry) on how to add a Desktop Entry for Alcritty with GNOME and it worked correctly.

Recently, after updating some dependencies, I noticed it disappeared from the GNOME Applications Menu. After looking through the dnf history, I found out that `orca` was upgraded to 41.0-2, `wireplumber` to 0.4.5-3 and `wireplumber-libs` to `0.4.5-3`.

I tried changing `Exec` to an absolute path - nothing. I tried changing the icon to PNG instead of SVG - again, nothing.

This is my current `Alacritty.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
TryExec=alacritty
Exec=alacritty
Icon=Alacritty
Terminal=false
Categories=System;TerminalEmulator;

Name=Alacritty
GenericName=Terminal
Comment=A fast, cross-platform, OpenGL terminal emulator
StartupWMClass=Alacritty
Actions=New;

X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.26

[Desktop Action New]
Name=New Terminal
Exec=alacritty
```

Comment: Is alacritty in a system path (`/usr/local/bin`) or your home (`$HOME/.cargo/bin`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who stumbled upon this issue, the OP posted a [resolution on GitHub](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/5631#issuecomment-979402738):

> you can fix it by changing `TryExec`, `Exec` (both inside `Desktop Entry` and `Desktop Action New`) to `/home/USER/.cargo/bin/alacritty`

I however preferred to leave those entries intact and just creating a symbolic link:

```bash
sudo ln -s /home/USER/.cargo/bin/alacritty /usr/local/bin/alacritty
```

which also fixed the issue.

(credits to @tvon who gave a [good hint here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678614/alacritty-desktop-entry-doesnt-show-on-gnome-41-1-fedora-35/712846#comment1320295_678614))